# Creating and displaying modal in onclick

Tags: javascript

So, I have code:

```
    function winModal(am)
{
    document.write('<div class="modal modal1 fade winmodal" id="winModal' + am + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">');
    document.write('<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog1 modal-lg">');
    document.write('<div class="modal-content modal-content1">');
    document.write('<div class="modal-body modal-body1">');
    document.write('<H2>Congratulations!</H2>');
    document.write('...');
    document.write('...');
    document.write('</div>');
    document.write('</div>');
    document.write('</div>');
    document.write('</div>');

    $('#winModal' + am).modal('show');
}
```

It works perfectly (creates a custom modal and displays it) since I use it at the end of the file, like winModal(100). When I want to use it in a button (onclick), it removes the content of whole site and replaces it with modal. I know why it's happening. (document.write overwrites content of site if it's loaded). I want to know how to make it work correctly. I tried innerHTML like that:

```
function winModal(am)
{
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '<div class="modal modal1 fade winmodal" id="winModal' + am + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog1 modal-lg">';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '<div class="modal-content modal-content1">';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '<div class="modal-body modal-body1">';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '<H2>Congratulations!</H2>';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '<h4>You have won <span style="font-weight:bold;">' + am + '</span> credits!</h4>';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '<h4>Go to <span style="font-weight:bold;">my winnings</span> to withdraw this or play more!</h4>';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '</div>';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '</div>';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '</div>';
    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = '</div>';

    $('#winModal' + am).modal('show');
}
```

However, it's not displaying the modal.

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the `string` each time to `document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML`.

```js
function winModal(am) {
  var htmlStr = "";
  htmlStr += '<div class="modal modal1 fade winmodal" id="winModal' + am + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">';
  htmlStr += '<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog1 modal-lg">';
  htmlStr += '<div class="modal-content modal-content1">';
  htmlStr += '<div class="modal-body modal-body1">';
  htmlStr += '<H2>Congratulations!</H2>';
  htmlStr += '<h4>You have won <span style="font-weight:bold;">' + am + '</span> credits!</h4>';
  htmlStr += '<h4>Go to <span style="font-weight:bold;">my winnings</span> to withdraw this or play more!</h4>';
  htmlStr += '</div>';
  htmlStr += '</div>';
  htmlStr += '</div>';
  htmlStr += '</div>';
  document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = htmlStr;
  $('#winModal' + am).modal('show');
}
```

Reason for 1st working is `document.write()` will `append` to html document.

In the 2nd `document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML` will `assign` the string.

Comment: Still wrong. Assigning the HTML string to `kkk` which does not exist

Comment: it works, thanks. the complete code is just a div with id "kkk" after this script and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you are overiding existing string with new string each time using `document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML` try to create the template and assign to the `kkk` element.

```
function winModal(am){

    var HTML = '<div class="modal modal1 fade winmodal" id="winModal' + am + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">'+
                    '<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog1 modal-lg">'+
                        '<div class="modal-content modal-content1">';
                            '<div class="modal-body modal-body1">'+
                                '<H2>Congratulations!</H2>';
                                '<h4>You have won <span style="font-weight:bold;">' + am + '</span> credits!</h4>'+
                                '<h4>Go to <span style="font-weight:bold;">my winnings</span> to withdraw this or play more!</h4>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';

    document.getElementById('kkk').innerHTML = HTML;

    $('#winModal' + am).modal('show');
}
```